# Reputation decrease automatically without any notification

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

I have show my reputations as 1605 in morning and later after 30 to 35 minutes when I check it shows me 1570 reputations and even I am not able to see any kind of notification regarding this decrease of reputations.

Comment: If the linked dupe does not answer the question, surely one of the many related articles --> over there will. If there is one thing that has been discussed front to back dozens of times, its reputation loss.